# create new list based how many times a value is listed in multiple list

Tags: python

I three different list. Each element in all the list are just phone numbers. How could I have my application create a new list that shows which list each phone number was in?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
July = load_workbook(filename="July.xlxs")
August = load_workbook(filename="August.xlxs")
September = load_workbook(filename="September.xlxs")
seven = July.active
eight = August.active
nine = September.active
list_7 = []
list_8 = []
list_9 = []
for row in seven.iter_rows(1. seven.max_row):
    list_7.append(row[0].value)
for row in eight.iter_rows(1, eight.max_row):
    list_8.append(row[0].value)
for row in nine.iter_rows(1, nine.max_row):
    list_9.append(row[0].value)
```

Comment: You could try using a dictionary = {"ph number" : list_num}

Comment: One way to do it is dictionary. Another way to do is to create a pandas dataframe and flag the phone number to the month. If flagged as 1 or True or Yes (bool is better), then the phone number is part of that month.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to the end of your code. It's not super efficient, but it gets the job done.

```
list_n = {}
for num in list_7:
  if list_n.get(num) is None:
    list_n[num] = {"list_7"}

for num in list_8:
  if list_n.get(num) is None:
    list_n[num] = {"list_8"}
  else:
    list_n[num].add("list_8")

for num in list_9:
  if list_n.get(num) is None:
    list_n[num] = {"list_9"}
  else:
    list_n[num].add("list_9")

print(list_n)
```

How it works step by step:

1. Create new dictionary "list_n"
2. Loop through list_7.
3. Check if each phone number in list_7 is in list_n.
4. If not, add the number to list_n and point it to a set. Let this set hold "list_7" as its value. This tells us that the phone number is in list_7.

Rinse and repeat for lists 8 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, use a dictionary

```
d = {}
for num in list_7:
    d[num] = 'list_7'
for num in list_8:
    d[num] = 'list_8'
for num in list_9:
    d[num] = 'list_9'
```